# how to get data in the reactJS using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios

I have reactJS class when I get a data in JSON and try to trasfrom it for html:

```js
class ProjectList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {projects: []};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:8080/project')
            .then(res => this.setState({ projects: res.data.name }))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            this.state.projects.map((project) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <p> {project.name} </p>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        )
    }
}
```

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <ProjectList />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I can undestand what is problem because have some problem with reactJS

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? make sure `this.state.projects.map` is inside `{ }` like `{  this.state.projects.map ( project => { return ... } ) } ` notice extra `{ }`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are storing `res.data.name` instead of `res.data`. Meaning `this.state.projects` is getting set to a single `name` string. You should be setting `this.state.projects` to `res.data` to get the full array of projects:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
        .get('http://localhost:8080/project')
        .then(res => this.setState({ projects: res.data }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```